# how to see jsp page in eclipse while designing?

Tags: eclipse

I was wondering is there any way to see the jsp page in eclipse while designing like we can in ***dreamweaver***, I did search this on *allmight* google but did't find anything helpful.. Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Eclipse Windows>Preferences>General>Editors?File Associations and Select .jsp. Make Web Page Editor as default in the below screen. So when you open any .jsp you see different views below.

Comment: @aash1230: actually I don't want to make my jsp run every time to see the view, that's my point "Like in Dreamweaver".